# scalable ios splash image in xamarin forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, layout, splash-screen

I am working with xamarin forms and now I am seting the IOS splash image in the splash.storyboard... I followed some tutorials and I setted "W any x H any" and "generic" in the configurations required...The image appears, it is a background image. The problems is: If I select the GENERIC option, the image is too large and in the iphone it doesnt seem good...I need a Scalable Splah image, how can I do that?
I am using windows for it...but I can use a mac too.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an ImageView into the ViewController instead of setting the BackgroundImage of the root view. With this, you can have the flexibility to set constraint according to your needs. You can learn more about auto layout [HERE](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/).

In addition, you can also set image with different resolution in iPhone and iPad inside your asset catalog.
[image]